# How to exclude other packages using setuptools in Python?

Tags: python

My file structure is as follows:

```
setup.py
src/
   package1/
      __init__.py
      modules1.py
   packages2/
      __init__.py
      modules2.py
   packages3
        .
        .
        .
```

I have a script that is going through and running `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --dist-dir` one at a time so I need to only build one package at a time.

My setup.py is as follows:

```
    setuptools.setup(
        name=name,
        version=version,
        package_dir={
        package_name:f"{directory}/{package_name}",
        },
        include_package_data=True,
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(where=directory, exclude=package_exclusion_list, include=[package_name+".*", package_name, "*.py"]),
        package_data={'': ['config.yaml', '*.json', '*.parquet']})
```

Here directory is the src directory. The issue is that they're for some reason packaging all together. How do I fix this so that it only packages 1 package at a time?